# Show element with specific content (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to address all li elements, which have a specific content without giving them a unique id/class?
like:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

All li's with the content "test" should get a red color.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'test';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cNfLP/).

Comment: Damn, you're just too fast :D

Comment: Thank's for your fast answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
$('li:contains("test")').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: nice try, but this would also append the red color to the 'test2'-li because 'test2' contains 'test' too :)

Comment: @user1116214 I guess filter is your only option if you are looking for exact matches

Answer (score 0):

[Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) should work pretty well for you here:

```
$('li')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "test" })
    .css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/KQPbA/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.list li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == 'test') {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
})
```